# XAMPP - MySQL Shutdown unexpectedly, even after changing the port

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have tried to change all the ports to **3007**. I have also tried to delete the `ibdata1` file in my `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder. Unfortunately none of these options worked for me.

The error log I get is the following:

```
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47215; transaction id 7
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 4 !!!
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200131  0:10:35
2020-01-31  0:10:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Edit: I reinstalled XAMPP and it worked. Not sure what happened or why it now works.

Comment: Is this a new MySQL server you setup?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes it is.